# Volume of a function calculated on a hypersphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, surfaces

I need help calculating the following integral on a sphere:

$$\int_{S^{n-1}}\  x_1 x_2 dS\left(x\right)$$

I tried using my assumption (not totally sure it's correct) that $\int_{S^{n-1}} \ {x_1}^2 = \frac{2\pi^\frac{n}{2}}{n\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$ to say that 
$$ 2\int_{S^{n-1}}\  x_1 x_2 dS\left(x\right) +  \int_{S^{n-1}} \ {x_1}^2 + \int_{S^{n-1}} \ {x_2}^2 = \int_{S^{n-1}} \ \left({x_1}+{x_2}\right)^2$$

Is this the way to go? If it is, how to proceed from now on? if not - what's wrong? (better yet - what's right? )

Comment: Exploit the symmetry.  Think of the $3$-D analog.  What are the values of $\oint_{S^2} xy\,dS$ or $\oint_{S^2} yz\,dS$, or $\oint_{S^2} xz\,dS$?